# How to enable hyperlink in UILabel

Tags: ios, xamarin

What I have is a `UILabel` (loaded with html) that I put on a `UIScrollView`.

In the html I have lots of links that I can´t get to "fire-up" when clicked.

I have added **UserInteractionEnabled = true** both on the `UILabel` and on the `UIScrollview` but I can´t get any reaction from the taps on the hyperlinks.

This is the code that create the label with the content.

```
        var attr = new NSAttributedStringDocumentAttributes();
        var nsError = new NSError();
        attr.DocumentType = NSDocumentType.HTML;

        var entry = "some text and url <a href='http://www.google.com'>url</a>";
        var myHtmlData = NSData.FromString(entry, NSStringEncoding.Unicode);

        contentLabel.AttributedText = new NSAttributedString(myHtmlData, attr, ref nsError);
        contentLabel.Frame = new CGRect(0, 20, scrollView.Frame.Size.Width  , scrollView.Frame.Size.Height);
        contentLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
        contentLabel.Lines = 0;
        contentLabel.SizeToFit();
```

Maybe this is just wrong.. putting html content into a label? But I don´t want to use a webview since it does not seem to scale that well.

Comment: Why not using a UITextView instead ? Enable Links detection and disable editable and Selectable option.

Comment: I don't believe Labels respond to taps.  I would use a button instead.

Comment: Tanks @ejanowski the selectable option made it work. If you like to add that as an answer I can except it.

Comment: @Sturla you're welcome, I have post the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not using a UITextView instead ? Enable Links detection and disable editable and Selectable option.

Comment: `UITextView` causes scroll-lag issue when using in `UITableView`. So, `UILabel` is the solution to this problem. But `UILabel` doesn't detect links.

Comment: just disable the scroll of uitextview.

Comment: For auto-height of `UITextView`, I have already disabled the scroll.

Answer (score 2):

Adding HTML to UILabel will not make it interactive. 
Use `UITextView` or https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel

Comment: Thanks. I used ended on using UITextView. TTTAttributeLable is a objective-c component that I can´t use in Xamarin C#. I have used it natively though and liked it. Thanks.